# Can I use "return" in here or any ideas?

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I'm really new to Java and most of my knowledge are self- taught. can you help me to figure out this.

Our teacher wants us to make a menu about Java. Where the output something like this..

Menu
1 - Java History
2- Java Keywords
3 - Java Arrays and so on. .

Do you want to read one (Yes/No):
//if yes

Please enter a menu number:
// then it will display an information..

//my problem is that how can I connect the new entered value to the first method so that I don't have write it all over again...

this is whats on my mind..
but im stuck..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program {

public static void main (String [] args) {

System.out.println("Please enter a number:");
int x = nextInt();

if (x == 1) {

     for (int x = 5; x == 5;x++) // array of 1(first menu)

System.out.println ("Do you want to read another? (Yes/No):");
System.out.println ("Please enter a menu number:")

// return to if with it's new entered value....

     }
    else if (x == 2)  {
    for loop of array 2

    System.out.println ("Do you want to read another? (Yes/No):");
    System.out.println ("Please enter a menu number:")

    // return to if with it's new entered value....


}   

else if (x == 3) {
    for loop of array 3

    System.out.println ("Do you want to read another? (Yes/No):");
    System.out.println ("Please enter a menu number:")

    // return to if with it's new entered value....


else if (x ==4) { 
    for loop of array 4

else if (x == 5) {
    for loop of array 5

else if (x == 6) {
    for loop of array 6

else if (x == 7) {
    for loop of array 7

else if (x == 8) {
    for loop of array 8

else if (x == 9) {
    for loop of array 9

else if (x == 10) {
    for loop of array 10

 else {
   //exit the program
```

Comment: you need a while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would want to implement the While or do while statement in your program. 
[Example of While and Do While Loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Im not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with your program but here is a little example I made quickly of how to utilize the for loop in your case. `import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean keepGoing = true; //As long as this is true the while statement will continue;
        while (keepGoing) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number");
            int x = scan.nextInt();

            //logic
            if (x == 1) {
                System.out.println("X is equal to 1");
            } else if (x == 2)
                System.out.println("X is equal to 2");


            //prompts the user if they want to keep going.
            System.out.println("Would you like to keep going? Y/N");

            String decision = scan.next();
            if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                keepGoing = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Quitting...");
                keepGoing = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
`
```

Comment: Yes but I don't exactly know how to do it in a way if it ask the user to enter a new value then that new value will be process again.

Comment: This code does that. It will keep prompting a user to enter a new number to be processed until he/she decides to quit. This is the work of the While loop in action.

Comment: Yeah it worked!!! Thank you very much!! It's a great help.. I finished my codes.. Show it to you next time. I'll put you in my acknowledgements if it's ok with you..